# WIFI connection drops randomly but regularly

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

My WIFI connection using `Centrino Wireless-N 2230` with `Ubuntu 18.04` drops randomly but regularly since weeks. In this state the wireless symbol changed into a questionmark - indicating a stale connection. This is just annoying, since automatic or manually triggered reconnection can take a couple of minutes. During this time the WIFI connection dialog pops up with credentials populated. But confirming this dialog does not reconnect successfully. A notable fact is that WIFI credentials from time to time are gone in Security Tab in this specific WIFI connection while in stale mode. After a reboot the credentials are restored. I really have problems to isolate the problem space. I might need help to find the root cause. What I need to provide to help with isolation and debugging ?

Kernel

```
wlp2s0: disassociated from 38:10:d5:7b:bd:05 (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
```

Logs

- [Syslog during connection drop](https://pastebin.com/MGvuUx5Q)

Kernel messages during boot phase

```
$ dmesg | grep wlp2s0
[   42.378817] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   62.596785] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   62.948957] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   63.043488] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   63.620989] wlp2s0: authenticate with 38:10:d5:7b:bd:05
[   63.624181] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:10:d5:7b:bd:05 (try 1/3)
[   63.626760] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   63.628001] wlp2s0: associate with 38:10:d5:7b:bd:05 (try 1/3)
[   63.633091] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 38:10:d5:7b:bd:05 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[   63.654196] wlp2s0: associated
[   63.671414] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 38:10:d5:7b:bd:05
```

Output of `nmcli device`

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION     
wlp2s0  wifi      connected    FRITZ!Box 7490 
enp4s0  ethernet  unavailable  --             
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Output of `system-resolve`

```
$ systemd-resolve --status wlp2s0
Link 3 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      fritz.box
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search fritz.box
options edns0
```

Output of `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

```
$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 192.168.178.1
search fritz.box
```

Wireless adapter

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: c4
       serial: 84:a6:c8:a3:00:02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-46-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.178.29 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff
```

My Ubuntu distribution

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the these three  commands @Sascha Gottfried? `nmcli device`, `systemd-resolve --status wlp2s0` and `ls -l /etc/resolve.conf`

Comment: Done. I could not find file /etc/resolve.conf`.

Comment: My mistake. It is `/etc/resolv.conf`. So give the command: `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Please @Sascha Gottfried, no long command. just give `nmcli device`. I want see your `hotspot` device.

Comment: Added. I extended the problem description to put emphasis on connection managed by network-manager.

Comment: Added output of `nmcli device`

Comment: Is `/etc/resolv.conf` a symlink or static? Please issue `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` command.

Comment: $ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mär 28  2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

Comment: Issue the command `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and please post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91642/discussion-between-sascha-gottfried-and-marmayogi).

Comment: Go to Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Fritz box -> "Gear" icon -> IPv4 menu item. You will see DNS section. What are the entries you see there? Please recall during chat, I said that there was "search fritz.box" entry  also found along with default nameserver 192.168.178.1.

Comment: How did you connect your Wi-Fi with Fritz box? Did you select the FRITZ!Box's wireless network (SSID) and then enter the FRITZ!Box's network key? Did FRITZ!Box ask you to enter network key?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with my Arch system. It was taking quite some time for the initial connection after each boot, random disconnects etc.
All I did to solve my problem was to change my router's channel. I guess there is interference when there are many wireless networks broadcasting on the same channel as your router around you.
You could use a tool like LinSSID to scan all nearby networks and pick a channel that is less used (or not used) by other routers.

```
sudo apt install linssid
```

It's a GUI tool so it should be pretty easy to work your way around it.

[image]

Comment: Nice tool. My WIFI router, a recent FRITZ!Box model, has a graphical WIFI scanner as a built-in feature. I already changed channel configuration from `Auto` to Manual and vice versa. This is not the root cause.

Comment: After chatting with @Marmayogi I suspect a problem here: network-manager has multiple connections with quite similar name like 'FRITZ!Box 7490', 'FRITZ!Box 7490 2', 'FRITZ!Box 7490 3', 'FRITZ!Box 7490 4'.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry I couldn't help. Honestly, I'm far from being a network expert... just thought that it might be the same issue.